# Query for find lowest near date to current date and time

Tags: mysql

I want to get a datetime from database by comparing it with current datetime and get nearest lowest datetime value.

For that, I have tried below code:

```
select * from videos order by abs(now() - Start_Time) limit 1
```

But, it will get nearest either lowest or highest.

Comment: Then try this one :
`SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY abs(now() - Start_Time) LIMIT 1 WHERE Start_time > now()`

Comment: It gives error " Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11 "

Comment: Try using a variable instead of now() i.e `Now_time = now()` and replace `now()` in the query with Now_time

Comment: i have tried variable but it will gives error call to undefined function now ()